# Is it possible to create an addon to firefox that generates one or more click events on a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox-addon

This is my first question! :)

I'll be specific:

- I need to interact directly and automatically with a specific web page!
- I need to access the elements on it like a specific `<a>` or a specific `<div>`, and generate a click event on that specific element!

I need to know if that's possible to do using an addon, because if it's not, my entire project falls apart :(!

(I tried to use a script on my page, but since the target page is on a different domain, it violates a basic rule/policy of JavaScript. So I couldn't do it that way...)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Well, Firebug and most browser developer tools let you add scripts/includes into a live web page, and then you can do whatever you want. Similarly, GreaseMonkey for Firefox allows you to do this in a more automatic way, and you can share such scripts with others more easily. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Comment: Hi Brian, thank you, that helped a lot :)

if you change your 'comment' to 'answer' i'll give it the check! ;)

Comment: Expanded and made into an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do that.

Following is the code that I have used in one of my private extensions.

```
var btn = document.getElementById(BTN_ID);;

if (btn) {

  var clickEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
  clickEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, document.defaultView, 
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  btn.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);

}
```

**Notes**

1. This needs to be done on or after DOMContentLoaded so that DOM elements become available
2. This is executed in content context (if you know what I mean)
3. Instead of using getElementById, you can use [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)() and pass it a selector string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Firebug and most browser developer tools let you add scripts/includes into a live web page, and then you can do whatever you want.

Similarly, [GreaseMonkey](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey) for Firefox allows you to do this in a more automatic way, and you can share such scripts with others more easily.

From the addon description:

> About this Add-on
>
> Allows you to customize the way a web page displays or behaves, by
>   using small bits of JavaScript.
>
> Hundreds of scripts, for a wide variety of popular sites, are already
>   available at http://userscripts.org.
>
> You can write your own scripts, too. Check out
>   http://wiki.greasespot.net/ to get started.